# getting type of dynamic key in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a  object that looks roughly like this:

```
const colors = {
    gray: {
        50: "#f9fafb",
        100: "#f3f4f6",
    },
    red: {
        50: "#fef2f2",
        100: "#fee2e2",
        200: "#fecaca",
    }
}
```

I am creating a helper function that returns a color from the `colors` object:

```
interface GetColor {
    (selector: keyof typeof colors, tint: // ...?): // ...?
}

const getColor = (selector, tint) => {
        return colors[selector][tint];
}
```

how do I get correct typings for the parameters (infer `tint` based on `selector` value) and return value?

Comment: They're all object properties, so they're all strings.

Comment: I know, what I meant was, is there a way to infer the type of `tint` as (50 | 100 | etc...) based on the `selector` value not just type number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an inline example using generics. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2IBOEYF4YG8CwAoGBMA5kgIYCeAXFnoXTAKwAM1ARAMQBmAnJ6ZwCNWAGlr0CARiYsYHTgGZOAFk4A2EWIIBfUfkJIApgBNqOPeOZsuBzgCY7G8-Sky5Bg7Y+PxBW9KucBsCkwd6EWngRuHigkLBEBlAAwiCISOgwADxiACowBgAeUAZgRqgA1gbkIJwwUOQADgY1cKnIEMIwYgDS+UUlZTCV1bX1TS0I7QDaOQC6eAB8ABQQBvBBUMiUOZ1QAJZgUJTdAJTUY821kygzs1Pds+gLNE50hlAArkhgrWkQU6t1sBNkg7vtDrMANyRPAxcDQOoSDIJZJtJBLADkJAoGM6LhOcLidVsyMSKTSmOx5FxMD8TBOMAA9IyYABBJBED4AWxKsBaFxgGLpGJge1QYBAsFIEAgeyIYFIAnWdRAMAapDIPOK6X5jQMgpcMAAPowmBjYbhYgioPJSaiKRjDEYaXSCdFLfDYFAlHbychMUqPgYafimSz2ZyeYcYLqmoLWIGDKwRWKYBKpTK5QqlfrNmqNaQtQYdaM9fGqaxjbIncmgA)

```
const colors = {
    gray: {
        50: "#f9fafb",
        100: "#f3f4f6",
    },
    red: {
        50: "#fef2f2",
        100: "#fee2e2",
        200: "#fecaca",
    }
}

const getColor = <T extends keyof typeof colors, K extends keyof typeof colors[T]>(selector:T, tint:K): typeof colors[T][K] => {
        return colors[selector][tint];
}

const t1 = getColor('gray', 100)
const t2 = getColor('gray', 200) // Argument of type '200' is not assignable to parameter of type '100 | 50'

const t3 = getColor('red', 200)

const t4 = getColor('blue', 100) // Argument of type '"blue"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"gray" | "red"'
```